# DB2 Performance CASE vs COALESCE

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization, case, coalesce

I'm modifying an existing statement that joins user information in one table so that the user info can come from another table.  One is a permanent table and the other is temporary (records get moved from one to the other).  I changed my join to a left join and then left joined the second contact info table.  I need to select the permanent field if it exists and the temporary if the permanent isn't there.  154306 is the user id of all incoming records on the main table I'm selecting from.  Here are my 2 options for selecting fields:

```
SELECT

CASE WHEN U.USRID = 154306
    THEN T.TMPFNAME
    ELSE U.FNAME
END AS FNAME,

COALESCE (U.LNAME, T.TMPLNAME) AS LNAME

FROM FILES.ORDERS O
LEFT JOIN FILES.USERS U ON U.USRID <> 154306 AND U.USRID = O.ORDUSR
LEFT JOIN FILES.TMPUSERS T ON O.ORDNUM = T.TMPORD
```

I'm thinking the case seems more "correct" as it's actually controlling the flow, but since the coalesce has less logic to follow it might perform faster.  Either should accomplish the same result because the 2 left joins ensures we'll get the info for the user no matter what, but don't get the permanent user info for orders which are still assigned to the temp user.  It looks like we have 10 fields to case/coalesce so I'm thinking the method with better performance is the way to go, which I think is coalesce but I'm not even sure on that.  Is either way better for any reason?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Performance on 1 call was trivial, it's when it goes live on a website that the load can be tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance of `case` versus `coalesce()` just will not make a difference to a query that is joining three large tables.  Such queries are dominated by the time for reading and matching the rows in the table.

By the way, the two are not *exactly* the same.  If you have `NULL` values in `users.Fname`, then the `case` logic would keep them but the `coalesce()` logic would fill in the values from the other table.

Your criterion should be clarity of expression.  Because you think the `case` makes more sense, I would suggest you go with that.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite helpful.  Apparently they misinformed me - records aren't moved from temp to permanent, they're copied, and not always copied.  We're just going to use coalesce so it grabs all information that's possible.  Good to know this for the future though :)